# Best way to fake static_assert inside if constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++20, static-assert, if-constexpr

As you may know static_assert does not care about if it is inside "active" branch of if constexpr(it always "runs").

I have a hack workaround that uses invalid array dimensions to trigger the error, but it is ugly.
Are there better solutions in C++20?

```
// does not work
template<typename T>
void argh(){
    if constexpr(sizeof (T)<123456 ) {

    } else {
        static_assert(0);
    }
}
// works but confusing to novice programmers, both code and error
template<typename T>
void meh(){
    if constexpr(sizeof (T)<123456 ) {

    } else {
        int error_triggering[-sizeof(T)];
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just `static_assert(sizeof (T)<123456)` and then maybe `if` without `else`?

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk and simply replace `if constexpr` with `static_assert`, since the other branch should never be followed at all.